# Render .glb / .gltf 3d model with PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, gltf, 3d-modelling

Is there a possibility to create or modify .glb or .gltf files in PHP?

For example, I want to load a .glb file, modify it and save it again, similar to "Image Processing and Generation"-functions.

**Pseudo code:**

```
$model = @modelcreatefromglb("model.glb");
modelstring($model, 5, 0, 0, 0, "Hello world!");
modelglb($model, "model-with-text.glb");
```

I only found a small library for "blender" (.blend-Files), but this is not the desired way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the PHP ecosystem doesn't really have many libraries for graphics APIs (OpenGL, Vulkan, Metal, etc.), and I couldn't find anything related to the glTF 2.0 format for the language. However, a `.gltf` file is just JSON, and you can parse its content with `json_decode( $gltfContent )`. Many changes, like changing materials or positions of objects, can be made just by modifying that JSON according to the glTF [specification](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/master/specification/2.0/README.md#concepts) or [quickstart guide](https://www.khronos.org/files/gltf20-reference-guide.pdf). The vertex and texture data is usually in separate files (`.bin`, `.png`, `.jpg`) which would require more careful parsing to work with.

A `.glb` is a binary file containing a small JSON header (equivalent content to a `.gltf`), followed by the binary vertex, animation, and texture data in one self-contained file. Parsing that is a bit more work but very doable. Here's [example code in JavaScript](https://github.com/donmccurdy/glTF-Transform/blob/7be7f9ddaab098af79b1eea3b67adac3d9c453ed/packages/core/src/io/platform-io.ts#L92-L121), if that's helpful.

Comment: Currently I'm trying to work with the structure of the file via JSON.... but I still hope that there is a function collection to edit the files.